# Onclick Event only worked with Double Click

Tags: jquery, html, datepicker

I use bootstrap-datetimepicker.js. I have to show the date-time picker on onclick event. It works only on double click.

```
<div class="col-sm-3">
  <label for = "name">Start Date</label>
  <div class='input-group date dateField'>
    <input type='text' class="form-control" name="start_date" placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm">
    <span class="input-group-addon" onclick='bindDatePicker();'>
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

```js
bindDatePicker = function() {
  $('.dateField').datetimepicker({
    format: 'DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm'
  });
}
```

I want to call that function on single click.
Any help will be grateful

Answer (score 1):

Firstly initialize with all the attributes you want in document ready then just use hide and show methods to toggle your datepicker

All functions are accessed via the data attribute

```
$('#datetimepicker').data("DateTimePicker").show();
```

You can use other [events](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Functions/) also if u want.

Use **onClick** or explicitly use a click event.

```
$('#datetimepicker-span').on('click', function(){

  //use show method here

});
```

Initialize first when document is ready.

Answer (score 1):

Actually just initializing the datepicker will do the job cause it's built in.
Use only:

```
 $('.dateField').datetimepicker({
    format: 'DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm'
 });
```

without `bindDatePicker()` event.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me

```
$('.dateField').datetimepicker({
format: 'DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm'
```

}).datetimepicker("show");